# When attempting to stub a request in Cypress IO (JS) against a React app using fetch, the requests still call through to the server

Tags: reactjs, fetch, cypress, stubbing

I'm using Cypress to create some specs against my React app. My react app uses fetch to fetch data from an external api (isomorphic-fetch)

The fetch requests in my app are like so

```
import fetch from 'fetch'
... 
fetch('http://www.external-server.com/ideas.json')
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
        }
        return response.json().then((result) => {
          this._data = result
          this._data((ele) => ele.key = ele.id)


        });
      })
```

In my Cypress specs, I want my regular specs to hit my lcoahost:3000 to get the initial page (which houses my React app). My react app in turn would normally make an external request (http://www.external-server.com/ideas.json) but in my specs I want to stub out that request and have that endpoint return fake data in my specs only.

The Cypress [docs for cy.route() here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Syntax), describe that I should be able to do something like

```
cy.server()
cy.route('http://www.external-server.com/ideas.json', [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'john'
  }
])
```

I attempted to put this into a beforeEach that runs in the context of my spec (thus running before every spec).

You will note that when I run the specs in the Cypress test running, it appears in the console output that the endpoint *SHOULD* be stubbed.

[image: Left panel of the cypress test runner showing the endpoint stubbed]

**However, by examination, I can see that my app is in fact making the request to  the real server, and calling the real endpoint (not stubbing it).**

I tested several times and I am certain this is the behavior.

I found a solution online I will post below to answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is add to `cypress/support/commands.js`

this small hack will turn the window fetch into a no-op (disabling it) and will allow the native stubbing in Cypress to work without any alterations.

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (originalFn, url, options) => {
  const opts = Object.assign({}, options = {}, {
    onBeforeLoad: (window, ...args) => {
      window.fetch = null;
      if (options.onBeforeLoad) {
        return options.onBeforeLoad(window, ...args);
      }
    },
  });
  return originalFn(url, opts);
});
```